# regex match from bash 3.2 to bash 4 (parse output from sql)

Tags: regex, bash, bash4

$SQL_RESULT is usually something like this:

```
TDM_PROC
-------------------------------------------------------------------
N
```

I need to extract the last word from it (N in this case).

In bash 3.2 I used this expression:

```
if [[ $SQL_RESULT =~ "(\w+)$" ]] ; then
  RES=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "Error" > $LOG_FILE
  exit 1
fi
```

I found that in bash 4 I should not use the quotes but it still does not work

```
if [[ $SQL_RESULT =~ (\w+)$ ]] ; then
  RES=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "Error" > $LOG_FILE
  exit 1
fi
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the exact bash version (bash --version)

Answer (score 2):

Use following BASH shell-option:

```
shopt -s compat31
```

to allow quoting in regex matching. With above option set you can do usual way:

```
if [[ $SQL_RESULT =~ "([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$" ]] ; then
  RES=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "Error" > $LOG_FILE
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in `bash 4.0`. Notice that I have used `$'\n'` to specify a newline before the `(..)` group. Additionally, I replace `\w` with `.`

```
 if [[ $SQL_RESULT =~ ^.*$'\n'(.+?)$ ]]; then RES=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; else echo '
```

no'; fi

```
echo $RES
N
```